# How to download a web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Index.cshtml with following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadPage", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
}
```

And Sample.cshtml with code like this:

```
@model string
<h1>@Model<h1>
```

I want to download Sample page when I press a button on Index.cshtml, like if I click right mouse button and select 'Save as..." line. How to do that?

Comment: What code have you got so far in the `DownloadPage` action?  What is it that you want to download - the raw `Sample.cshtml` file, or the resultant page that `Sample.cshtml` would produce?

Comment: I want to download resultant page of Sample.cshtml. Actually, I don't know that should be in the DownloadPage action

Comment: It sounds like you want to render the `Sample` action to a string, and then return the response as a download to the browser?  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774856/render-action-to-string to get your started.

Comment: We can use WebClient for download file. but in your case you need to download dynamically created view. WebClient works only static files. So first save your dynamically created view Sample.cshtml to xyz.html and use WebClient to download that file on same event.

Comment: Ok, how I can get html file from cshtml? When project compiles, I get just .dll library